# Where to put 3thd party lib not in packagist

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I wonder where should we put a third party lib (js+css+src) on a symfony 2/3 project that are not from packagist ?
I bet for :

- a "lib" folder in the project root.
- in "web" folder
- in my AppBundle/Resources/public/

What is your opinion on this ?

thanks

Comment: This depends on the nature of the library.  Is it your code?  Then it should be in a bundle.  If it is some library that isn't in packagist there are ways to declare alternative repos.  You can also take that code and stick it into github and use it from there, again via some additional configuration in your composer.json.

Comment: Thanks, but what about a lib that dont have a github repo ? Like I just download a zip from a website ?

Comment: As I covered, you have all the options listed.  You can stick it into a github repo of your own, unless the license specifically forbids doing so.  You can [setup your own private packagist](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md).  You can also [reference the zip file](https://donatstudios.com/Require-a-Remote-Zip-File-with-Composer).

Comment: Thanks this is what i looking for. You can post it as an answer to validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it your code? Then [it should be in a bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html).

If it is some library that isn't in packagist there are ways to declare alternative repos. You can also take that code and stick it into github account use it from there, again via some additional configuration in your composer.json.

- You can [stick it into a github repo of your own](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own), unless the license
  specifically forbids doing so.
- You can [setup your own private packagist](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md).
- You can [also reference the zip file](https://donatstudios.com/Require-a-Remote-Zip-File-with-Composer).